# Segfault in move assingment

Tags: c++, c++14

I have created a MVP of my code which causes segfault when attempting a move operation. The move assignment does not seem to be able to call the move constructor, but instead calls itself and after looping for a while the program segfaults. I have tried multiple things but found only solution through const_cast, which I'd prefer not to use. Are there other ways to fix this?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class test
{
private:
    const bool useful;
public:
    test(bool u);
    ~test();
    test(test&& t);
    test& operator=(test&& t);
};

test::test(bool u) : useful(u) {}
test::~test() {}
test::test(test&& t) : useful(t.useful) {}

test& test::operator=(test&& t)
{
    if (this != &t)
    {
        *this = std::move(t);
    }

    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    test A(false);
    test B(true);

    A = std::move(B);
}
```

Comment: `The move assignment does not seem to be able to call the move constructor` Of course it doesn't. You can't move-construct an already existing object. Thats why we have move-assignment in the first place.

Comment: `*this = std::move(t);` invokes move assignment operator. Endless recursion causes stack overflow.

Comment: you need to swap instead of calling `=` operator

Comment: `*this = std::move(t);` is equivalent to `(*this).operator=(std::move(t));`